# Nagios SNMP: Different OIDs for the same value

Tags: bash, snmp, ubiquiti

With Nagios, I want to read a device name of hundreds of Ubiquity devices. This value has one OID on some of them and another on others. The best way I got so far is using this script:

```bash
$1/check_snmp -H $2 -o .1.2.840.10036.3.1.2.1.3.5 > /tmp/$2.snmp.nagios.tmp
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  $1/check_snmp -H $2 -o .1.2.840.10036.3.1.2.1.3.9 > /tmp/$2.snmp.nagios.tmp
  status=$?
fi
cat /tmp/$2.snmp.nagios.tmp
exit $status
```

What I don't like here is that it uses filesystem, but I don't know how to read output of a command to one variable and exit code of the command to another variable.

Is there a way to write this so it uses variables only?

Isn't there a better way to achive the main goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directly the command snmpget instead check_snmp  because check_snmp will use snmpget (or other tool of netsnmp tools) and works on the result stored in a variable.

I paste here the skeleton of a script I use for that :

```
function control_error {
    echo "UNKNOWN : Error during operation" 
    exit 3
}
drive="$(snmpget -v1 -Ovq -c <community snmpv1> $IPadress .1.3.6.1.4.1.2.3.51.3.1.13.1.3.1.2.$i)"
if [ $? != 0 ]; then control_error;fi
drive="$(echo $drive | sed -e 's/"//g')"
...
```

This script read an OID and store the result in the variable drive.

it tests the evental error of snmpget and return 3 (unknown for nagios) if problem.

The snmpget options are :

- -v1 version of snmp
- -c community
- -Ovq OUPUT options which returns only the result without the asked OID

After you can work on your variable for example in this script with echo and sed

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this:

```bash
data=$(your command)
result=$?
```

This way you get the output of your command in `$data` and the return code in `$result`. But maybe there is a much nicer way.